# IntelliJ: No "Run as" option

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I installed IntelliJ 2021.2.3 Ultimate edition and when I make the right click on a project, I don't see the run as an option. The window shows like below:

[image]

My intention is to set the maven goal to create a docker image for the project. Now, I do I set the maven goal?

Comment: "More Run/Debug" (?)

Comment: @xerx593 installed the plugin and this works fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the solution and would like to present it as this may help someone as well. I installed the maven plugin and then, restart the IDE that enables options.

[image]

[image]